# CSS block on top of image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create something like this(without the blue lines):
[image]

The grey is a picture that I have to insert and the letters must be displayed above.

I've tried to do it on my own but I can't

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried yet? I recommend to read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it contains a clear explanation of how questions should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `<img>` tag into a `div` wrapper, put a second `div` *into* the first one (after the `img`), write the text into that div and use CSS rules like

```
.my_div_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
.my_image {
  width: 100%;
)
.my_text_over_image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The important thing is the absolute position. The last number in the background setting is the opacity of the background color. Choose color and opacity (and everything else) as desired).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a codepen with one idea of how to solve this:

http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/ENPNjq

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sometext {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.istoe.com.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2016/11/0eea5026741522fcaacbdc814652bfc5dce89aed-768x432.jpg" alt="" />
  <p class="sometext">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

You have to work with z-index to have an element over another. I'm sure there are many other implementations for this problem, this was my quick answer, hope it helps you.

I really recommend this blog post to better understand z-index, and what is really going on in this situation: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Image in the background using `background-img` property and place the items over it using the `position: absolute` and making the background `position: relative`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/200');
  position: relative;
}

.bg-img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}


.link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}

.arrow {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="child text">Hello World</span>
    <span class="child arrow">-></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!